# Android Recycler view to load images from gallery using Async Task

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I am developing an image gallery app. I want to set all the images in imageview using Async Task. My app is slow. I want to update recycler view after every image path obtained from android phone.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `AsyncTask` is deprecated since some months. I would suggest to take an Image-Loading-Library like *Glide*. You can find a good example here:

https://javapapers.com/android/android-image-gallery-example-app-using-glide-library/

Then you can easily create yourself a `RecyclerView` and implement your adapters `onBindViewHolder` method like:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {    
    Glide.with(context)
        .load(imageUrls.get(i).getImageUrl())
        .into(viewHolder.img);
}
```